# Continuity and Differentiation of a specific function

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the function
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^ncos(4^nx)$$
is continuous every where on $\Bbb R$ and nowhere differentiable when $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\pi}{8}<a<1$.

My attempt:

I encountered this question during my advanced engineering mathematics and I know it's related to continuity (whether uniform or not). There are many different theorems there stating that if a bunch of sequential functions $f_n$ tend to some function $f$ (which probably we don't know all the specifics) then many of $f_n$ s' properties are preserved also for function $f$ such as integrability and differentiability. I know this theorem but I don't know where to start. I appreciate any idea helping me solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: [The Weierstrass Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function)

Comment: But how do I start an idea? Would you plz elaborate?